# Java Unsupported major minor Version 52? Why does this happen though I didn't use new features from Oracle Java 1.8?

Tags: java, jar, compatibility, java-8, sun

I am just learning Java. I compiled and created a jar file for a simple quiz game with a  light GUI. All done from Ubuntu 14.04 terminal manually with '`javac -d ...`' and '`jar -xvmf...`'

Here are my version details:

```
java version "1.8.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_11-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.11-b03, mixed mode)

javac 1.8.0_11
```

I followed a tutorial dealing with Java SE 5.0 for creating it, so I guess no new features from '1.8' were used. It compiled and it worked fine for me. When my friend who uses OpenJDK (latest version available) in Ubuntu 14.04 tried running it he received a lot of errors including ***Unsupported major minor ... 52...***.

I don't have the full verbose output from the terminal. Is there any way to avoid this and why is this happening though I didn't use use any new features specific to the latest version?

I thought Java was supposed to be ***"Write Once ,Run Everywhere"***, and compatibility issues with even the simplest of things with just a slightly little older version involved makes me rethink things!

Comment: If you compile a Java class with 1.8 you can only run it on 1.8. If you want to run it on earlier versions you need to specify `-target` parameter. See the manual for details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCJDCID

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version of the byte code doesn't depend on whether you use Java 8 new features or not. It simply depends on which compiler you use. A Java 8 compiler will by default produce Java 8 bytecode, unless you use the option `-target` to specify an earlier version.

Side note: your friend is not using the latest version of OpenJDK (which is Java 8), otherwise, he would not get this exception.

Comment: How low should i target it , 1.5? considering all i used it ArrayLists , Frames etc at most.

Comment: It depends on who will use your app, how you will distribute it/install it, etc. I would stick with the default, and document the fact that your app needs Java 8. It's far less dangerous to do that: no risk of using a method that doesn't exist in the target, no risk of hitting a bug of previous versions of Java that doesn't exist anymore in Java 8, etc. If you want to target Java 5, you should develop with Java 5.

Comment: Just FYI, Ubuntu still doesn't have Java 8 as part of official repositories yet (Launchpad etc). If you want to  use java 8 you have to manually download it yourself.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-8/+bug/1297065